# Java Spring: AnnotationSessionFactoryBean, Hibernate-Dialect AutoDetection

Tags: spring, hibernate, dialect

I use the following spring application context:

```
<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <!--
             <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
          -->
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">${hibernate.max_fetch_depth}</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_query_cache}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${hibernate.cache.provider}</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">1000</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
          ...
       </list>
    </property>

    <property name="schemaUpdate" value="${hibernate.schemaUpdate}"/>
</bean>
```

**Then problem is: Although Hibernate should support Dialect-Autodetection this code doesnt work:** Uppon Application-Init the following exception is thrown:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: The dialect was not set. Set the property hibernate.dialect.
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.instantiateDialect(Dialect.java:256)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getDialect(Dialect.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getDialect(Dialect.java:249)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean$3.doInHibernate(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:957)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:419)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:339)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.updateDatabaseSchema(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:953)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterSessionFactoryCreation(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:843)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:213)
```

*I can avoid this exception by uncommenting the hibernate.dialect property. Why do I have to do this? Why cant hibernate just autodetect the dialect like it is supposed to?*

I want do remove the dialect-property to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432193/java-dbunitils-spring-different-hibernate-dialect) problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hibernate itself **tries** to auto-detect dialect during `Configuration.buildSessioNFactory()` call - and usually, though not always, succeeds.

Spring code, however, does not - and that's where you get the exception. `LocalSessionFactoryBean.updateDatabaseSchema()` method uses `Dialect.getDialect()` method to obtain `Dialect` instance which requires dialect to be explicitly set.

I'm not quite sure why it's done that way, though I suspect it's a precaution against Hibernate mistakenly detecting your dialect incorrectly and messing up your database as a result (since updating schema can potentially be quite disastrous).

Your options are:

1. Explicitly specifying dialect
2. Setting `schemaUpdate` to false
3. Extending LocalSessionFactoryBean and overriding `updateDatabaseSchema()` method to take the (already auto-detected) dialect from session factory instance.

You'll have to class cast it to SessionFactoryImplementor for that:

```
public void updateDatabaseSchema() throws DataAccessException {
  final Dialect dialect = ((SessionFactoryImplementor) getSessionFactory()).getDialect();
  ...
  hibernateTemplate.execute(new HibernateCallback() {
    ...
    // you already have the dialect so you don't need to get it using this:
    // Dialect dialect = Dialect.getDialect(getConfiguration().getProperties());
    ...
  );
}
```